# Example about Constant time algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I have read some meaning of constant time algorithm that is

Constant Time: O(1)

An algorithm is said to run in constant time if it requires the same amount of time regardless of the input size. Examples:

array: accessing any element

fixed-size stack: push and pop methods

fixed-size queue: enqueue and dequeue methods

but i still don't get it clearly about the example above.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't clear?

Comment: Get what clearly? fixed -time - ALWAYS takes the same amount of time, regardless of how much/little work is actually being performed.

Comment: @MarcB That actually doesn't make any sense. Time is proportional to work done (in non-parallelized algorithms, which is the kind we're talking about here).

Comment: yes, but "time" isn't a fixed value for this. if accessing array element [0] takes (say) 1 second, then accessing array element [10 billion] will also take 1 second. Even though the elements are theoretically separated by ~9.9 billion other elements, both accesses take the SAME amount of time.

Comment: I just want some code or psudocode of the example :)

Comment: @MarcB Right, but that's because they both take the same amount of work to do (calculate the address, get thing from address). Saying that something can take the same amount of time and different amounts of work is what doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @user3103918 A code example isn't really applicable. This is more about understanding that those operations take the same number of steps to perform no matter how many elements the array/stack/queue is holding.

Answer (score 7):

The english meaning of constant time and O(1) are actually slightly different.

O(1) means upperbounded by a constant, i.e a function that is bounded above by a constant. Note, it does not say same for each input.

For instance consider the method

```
uint f(uint n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        printf("111");
    } else {
        printf("111222333");
    }
}
```

This will take different times, depending on whether n is even or not (plus other unknown factors, like OS etc).

We still call it O(1) as it is theoretically the runtime is bounded by a constant: if say measured in number of instructions executed. This type of metric is important when talking about complexity (and is usually implicit in discussions). You need to have an underlying model of computation before talking of complexity.

Usually people think of the unit cost [word ram](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-cpp/1_3_Model_Computation.html) model which models the current modern computer closely. Every instruction there is of unit cost (including memory access) and the time complexity is measured in number of instructions executed. This is the usual model used when people talk about complexities (in textbooks/interview questions etc).

In that model, the above sample will take no more than a fixed number of instructions, even though it might vary for some inputs, it will still be lesser than that number, and is O(1).

The reason we can say it is 'constant', is that we can pad with NO-OPS to make each execution to take the same number of instructions.